# Update a row in sqlite table Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sql-update, android-sqlite

I am trying to update 2 values in a row of table which also contain another 7 values which is not changed. 
Code for update:

```
 public int UpdateItem(int tableId, String itemname, String modifiername, int count, double totalPrice) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_QUANTITY, count);
        values.put(DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE, totalPrice);

                  return db.update(DbSchema.KOT_TABLE, values, DbSchema.TABLE_ID + " = " + tableId +
                        " AND " + DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_NAME + " = '" + itemname +
                        "' AND " + DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_MODIFIER_NAME + " = '" + modifiername + "'",
                null);

    }
```

Call for update is from a itemclick of an Adapter:

```
 holder.incrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = Integer.parseInt(holder.itemCount.getText().toString());
                holder.itemCount.setText("" + (count + 1));
                filteresKotItemArrayList.get(position).setOrderedItemQuantity(count + 1);
                Double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(holder.totalAmount.getText().toString()) + kotItem.getOrderedItemBasePrice();
                holder.totalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
                filteresKotItemArrayList.get(position).setOrderedItemTotalPrice(totalPrice);

                dbOpenhelper.UpdateItem(kotItem.getTableId(), kotItem.getOrderedItemnme(), kotItem.getOrderedItemModifierName(), (count + 1), totalPrice);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

In model class it is working but db it is not updating. When i reopen the current list by updating db its not updated their.

```
kotItemList = dbOpenhelper.getKOTList(tableId);
```

No error is showing. How can i update that row 
also use query to do that but no Result.

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE " + DbSchema.KOT_TABLE + " SET " +
                DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_QUANTITY + " = " + count + ","
                + DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE + " = " + totalPrice +
                " WHERE " + DbSchema.TABLE_ID + " = " + tableId +
                " AND " + DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_NAME + " = '" + itemname +
                "' AND " + DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_MODIFIER_NAME + " = '" + modifiername + "'";
db.execSQL(strSQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your where clause that cause an issue.
for a try just update values using only where clause --- DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_NAME = "xyz".
Also check that DbSchema.ORDERED_ITEM_NAME value is exists in your table

Comment: value is there Also updated in model class but not in db @cansel

Comment: can you log sql statement (with values and where clause) and share it.